# Partition function for a $SO(3, 1)$ invariant "Hamiltonian"

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, partition-function, invariants

Suppose, I look at the $SO(3, 1)$ generalization of $H = \frac{p^2}{2m}$, i.e. $$H = \lambda P^{\mu}P_{\mu}$$ where $P^{\mu}P_{\mu}$ is a $SO(3, 1)$ invariant object and $\lambda$ is some dimensionful constant (It's just hypothetical. It may not describe a physical system as such.). If I consider the quantum partition function of the above then we have

$$Z_{quantum} = \sum_{eigenvalues} e^{\beta H} = \int^{\infty}_0 dm ~e^{-\beta\lambda m^2} = \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dm ~e^{-\beta \lambda m^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta\lambda}} $$ where $m$ is the mass because the eigenstates of $P^2$ are the mass eigenstates. However, if I consider the classical partition function then we would have
$$Z_{classical}= V\int^{\infty}_0 dm\int \delta(P^2+m^2)\Theta(P^0) d^4P ~e^{\beta\lambda P^2} = V\int^m_0 dm\int \frac{d^3\vec{P}}{2(2\pi)^3\sqrt{m^2+\vec{P}^2}} e^{-\beta\lambda m^2} = \left(V\int\frac{d^3\vec{x}}{2(2\pi)^3\sqrt{1+\vec{x}^2}}\right)\int^m_0 m e^{-\beta\lambda m^2}$$
where $V$ is the full spacetime volume $\vec{x} = \vec{P}/m$. Also, I have made use of an $SO(3, 1)$ invariant measure to perform the integration. Can someone comment on whether  my calculations make sense? Or point out any conceptual errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your quantum partition function, you implicitly assumed that the eigenvalues $m^2$ are non-degenerate. In your classical partition function, you have an extra term
$$V\int{d^3\vec P\over 2(2\pi)^3\sqrt{m^2+P^2}}$$
that corresponds to the density $g(m)$ of eigenvalue $m^2$ (in the limit of $m$ large). The partition function is
$$Z=\int g(m)e^{\beta\lambda m^2}dm$$
Taking into account the degeneracy of the eigenvalues, the quantum partition function should give something similar when going from the sum to the integral.

Comment: Hmmm. Good point. Is it possible to comment on the degeneracy of the eigenvalues from the Hamiltonian? Or maybe the degeneracy of the mass eigenvalues is related to the dimension of the little group or something?